# Button's click event not responding in listview

Tags: android, listview, button, onclicklistener

I have a listview consisting of text and button in each row. I have to implement the click listener for every button residing in the row but i am not able to do so. i have also checked different from SO, but could not get desired result. For that i have implemented custom adapter as:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String[] strings = { "jjacj", "kpomkn", "jjbjbj nk", "njbhvh",
            "mknkn", "mnknlhn", "lknkn", "mknkn"};
    Holder holder = null;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return strings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child_category,
                    null);
            holder.mTxtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_notification);
            holder.mButtonTag = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnNotify);
            holder.mLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
            // convertView.setOnClickListener(callback);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.mTxtTitle.setText(strings[position]);
        holder.mButtonTag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnSelection();
            }
        });

        if (position == 0) {
            holder.mLayoutMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_table_top);
        } else if (position == getCount() - 1) {
            holder.mLayoutMain
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_table_bottom);
        } else {
            holder.mLayoutMain
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_table_middle);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    OnClickListener callback = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnSelection();
        }
    };

    private void btnSelection() {
        if (holder.mButtonTag.getTag().equals("no")) {
            holder.mButtonTag.setTag("yes");
            holder.mButtonTag.setText("NEI");
            holder.mButtonTag.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.mButtonTag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_nei);
            holder.mButtonTag.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            holder.mButtonTag.setTag("no");
            holder.mButtonTag.setText("JA");
            holder.mButtonTag.setPadding(0, 0, 20, 0);
            holder.mButtonTag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_ja);
            holder.mButtonTag.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    static class Holder {
        Button mButtonTag;
        TextView mTxtTitle;
        RelativeLayout mLayoutMain;
    }
}
```

List Child Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_table_middle" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_notification"
        style="@style/textview_layout"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNotify"
        style="@style/button_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my view:

[image]

Can anybody please let me know where i am lacking or any changes should be done to get atleast a toast on each button residing in the list.
Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You sure your imports are correct. One addition you can add the listener only when convertedView is null.

Comment: Can you please describe what result you get with this code? What issue occur here?

Comment: your listview might be interrupting while getting click,put something like this inside your xml `<ListView android:clickable="false"></ListView>`

Comment: Thank you guys for replying, but i have already implemented this but of no use.:(

Comment: Result: on clicking on any button in list randomly changes another button without affecting to that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the view as argument in your function like this

```
private void btnSelection(View button) {
    if (button.getTag().equals("no")) {
        button.setTag("yes");
        ((Button)button).setText("NEI");
        button.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_nei);
        ((Button)button).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    } else {
        button.setTag("no");
        ((Button)button).setText("JA");
        button.setPadding(0, 0, 20, 0);
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_ja);
        ((Button)button).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

and in the `getView` method change `OnClickListener` as this

---

add befor the click listener in `getView`

```
if (holder.mButtonTag.getTag() == null)
  holder.mButtonTag.setTag("");
```

---

```
holder.mButtonTag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnSelection(v);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: still it changes randomly. I mean on clicking on any button changes another button.

Comment: I have a question. On clicking on the button, does the correct button is changed and after scrolling its random, or as u click on the button its always random?

Comment: when i click any particular button, that button does not change in fact another random button changes.

Comment: @AkashG: I have updated my answer and tested it on my side. I am getting a positive result, hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you @AnujMathur, it works. now can u please let me know how can we get status of each button whether it is selected or not??

Comment: you can check the text of the button...i.e. if its "NEI" or "JA"

Answer (score 0):

change in your xml file as shown below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  
        android:background="@drawable/bg_table_middle" > 

     <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txt_notification"
           style="@style/textview_layout"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

      <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNotify"
            style="@style/button_layout" 
            android:focusable="false" />
```

and also put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`  in your listview xml file for main layout.And also put `android:focusable="false"` in listview.

```
holder.mButtonTag.setId(position);
holder.mButtonTag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnSelection();
            }
        });
```

Comment: i tried this but its not working :(. Also removed focus from list and provided to layout but still no change

Comment: have you put android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in your listview xml main layout,

Comment: yes i did but not getting desired result.Result: on clicking on any button in list randomly changes another button without affecting to that button

Answer (score -1):

Change Button code to

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnNotify"
style="@style/button_layout" 
  android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```